# postgresql , ADD CONSTRAINT error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

rails db:migrate
gives error:= ***type "email_must_be_company_email" does not exist..***

the migration file is............

```
class AddEmailConstraintToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def up
     execute %{
       ALTER TABLE users
       ADD CONTRAINT ***email_must_be_company_email***
       CHECK ( email ~* '^[^@]+@example\\.com'  )
      }  
  end  

  def down
    execute %{
      ALTER TABLE users
      DROP CONTRAINT ***email_must_be_company_email***
    }
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled the word CONSTRAINT as CONTRAINT so postgres is interpreting it as a column name and email_must_be_company_email as the column type.